# Update multiple rows in table from table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a stored procedure to update multiple records based on a table variable parameter.

The existing table is: **Tb_Project_Image** with relevant columns:

```
id PK (identity 1,1) 
cat_ord decimal(4,2)
```

The procedure will receive a temporary table variable (shown in the code below) containing the id as `PI_ID`, and the new value for `cat_ord` as `newCatOrd`. `idx` is a simple identity for each row containing 1...n where n is the rowcount of `@tempTable`.

For each row in `@tempTable`, I want to update `Tb_Project_Image` where `id = PI_ID` to the corresponding value.

```
    DECLARE @tempTable table (
    idx smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1),
    PI_ID bigint, 
    newCatOrd decimal(4, 2) not null )

    INSERT INTO @tempTable values (3, 7.01)
    INSERT INTO @tempTable values (4, 7.02)
    INSERT INTO @tempTable values (5, 7.03)
    --etc...
    DECLARE @error int
    DECLARE @update int
    DECLARE @iter int
    SET @iter = 1

    BEGIN TRAN
WHILE @iter <= (select COUNT(*) from @tempTable)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Tb_Project_Image
        SET cat_ord = (SELECT newCatOrd FROM @tempTable 
                        WHERE idx = @iter)
        WHERE id = (SELECT PI_ID FROM @tempTable
                        WHERE idx = @iter)  
        --error checking            
        set @error = @@ERROR
        set @update = @@ROWCOUNT
        IF ((@error = 0) AND (@update = 1))
            BEGIN
            SET @iter = @iter + 1
            CONTINUE
            END
        ELSE
            BREAK
    END

IF ((@error = 0) AND (@update = 1)) 
    COMMIT TRAN
ELSE
    ROLLBACK TRAN
GO
```

Now, the error checking is because, to ensure integrity, EACH row in the temporary table MUST make 1 update. (explanation omitted to save space) If a single iteration of the while loop threw an error, or didn't effect exactly 1 row, I want to break the loop and rollback the transaction

THE PROBLEM I'm having is that this error checking is not working. I'm currently running it with 14 rows in `@tempTable` and the 11th uses a `PI_ID` not found in the `Project_Image` table. Therefore, `@update = 0...` but it continues the loop and commits the data.

I'd be doubly glad if someone had a method of doing this that only used a single update statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it this way, because even SET resets the state of @@ERROR and @@ROWNUMBER variables. In this case @@ROWCOUNT is set to 1 after `set @error = @@ERROR`. If you do not assign the values to local variables, your code will work:

```
IF ((@@error = 0) AND (@@rowcount = 1))
```

But you might rather try [try...catch error handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) and test @@rowcount separately after update.

**UPDATE:** doing it in single update:

```
UPDATE t
   SET cat_ord = tt.newCatOrd
  FROM Tb_Project_Image t
 INNER JOIN @tempTable tt
    ON t.id = tt.PI_ID
-- If there was PI_ID not found in Tb_Project_Image
-- But I think that this should have been dealt with
-- During the initial loading of temporary table
IF @@ROWCOUNT <> (select count (*) from @tempTable)
BEGIN
   -- Error reporting here
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: You can also set both @@ERROR and @@ROWNCOUNT to variables if you do it in a single statement... `SELECT @error = @@ERROR, @update = @@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you. And yes, this safety net will probably never get tripped in the run of things, but I like to be cautious. I was mostly using the rollback because I had multiple updates in my initial code. Thank you for showing me a way to get it all done in one shot as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating and then rolling back, you could also use a CTE to determine if any records should be updated prior to performing the update.  Something like this should work:

```
WITH NON_SINGLETON AS (
    -- Find any records in @tempTable that don't match
    -- exactly one record in Tb_Project_Image
    SELECT t.PI_ID, COUNT(pi.id) C
    FROM @tempTable t
    LEFT JOIN Tb_Project_Image pi ON t.PI_ID = pi.id
    GROUP BY t.PI_ID
    HAVING COUNT(pi.id) != 1
)
UPDATE Tb_Project_Image
SET cat_ord = t.newCatOrd
FROM Tb_Project_Image pi
JOIN @tempTable t ON pi.id = t.PI_ID
-- If any invalid records were found in the CTE,
-- then this condition will fail for all rows
-- and nothing will be updated
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM NON_SINGLETON)
```

If it's possible for `@tempTable` to have duplicate entries for the same `PI_ID`, then this will handle those scenarios as well.  And since it's a single statement, you don't have to explicitly managing the transaction in the proc (if it's the only thing that needs to be included in the transaction).